# In pandas, how to turn a dataframe into tidy data?

Tags: python, pandas, charts, transpose, tidy

In python and pandas I have a dataframe that I need to turn into tidy data to make charts easier

The original data is like this:

[image]

I want to transform into a dataframe, with the transposition of the data and adapting column names:

[image]

Please is there a way in python to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt):

```
out = df.melt('year', var_name='localization', value_name='number_of_tests')
```

You can also use:

```
out = df.set_index('year').rename_axis(columns='localization').unstack() \
        .rename('number_of_tests').reset_index()
```